# Basic similarity of triangles problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

The question is to find the length of AB. I'm currently studying civil engineering, but I'm trying to refresh some old knowledge as I got a part time job this semester as a math assistant at a middle school. You're not supposed to use trigonometry.

My attempt involves similarity of triangles of course, since all the angles are obviously identical.

$\frac{AB}{AD} = \frac{3}{6}$

$\frac{AB}{AB+BD} = \frac{1}{2}$

In the solution they somehow know that the length of BD is 4. I figured out that they're at least equal using trigonometry, but I don't see where the 4 comes from.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

The picture in the question is missing $BD = 4$.

From $\frac{AB}{AB+4} = \frac{1}{2}$, we have $2 AB = AB + 4$, so $AB=4$.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to guess. You're supposed to find the length of AB. If you make that guess, you basically guessed the solution.

Comment: @novo That's true, but the problem doesn't really make sense. Problems similar to this have another side given, so that you can find the side using similarity ratios.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the assistance. The problem is taken from https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/similar-triangles/similar-triangles-theory-and-problems.html example 3

Comment: @novo The picture is probably missing $BD = 4$. If this is added in, all their steps make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more information here than the problem requires.

Since they are right triangles, you know by Pythagoras that$$AB^2+BC^2=AC^2$$
And since $BC= 3$, then if we grant that $5^2$ and $4^2$ are the  only two square numbers that differ by $3^2$, it will follow that $AC=5$ and $AB=4$. No trigonometry needed, nor similar triangles.

On the other hand, allowing for irrational numbers, supposing $AC=\sqrt{24}$, $\sqrt{23}$,  or $\sqrt{22}$, then by Pythagoras $AB=\sqrt{15}$, $\sqrt{14}$, or $\sqrt{13}$, respectively. We know in every case that $AB=BD$, but beyond that? The problem seems indeterminate, and again similarity of triangles is no help.